# Change NA values in raster layers and loop in several layers

Tags: r, loops, raster, r-raster

I would like to change `-1` values to `NA` values (-9999) in my ascii layers using the `raster` package in R.
I know how to do this with one ascii layer, but would like to repeat this in multiple layers. I would like the output files to be named as the input files. 
Here is my code:

```
asc <- raster("DAAC_AWC_CLASS.asc")

NAvalue(asc) <- -1

writeRaster(asc, filename="C:/Users/xblajo/Desktop/New folder/2/DAAC_AWC_CLASS.asc", 
            format="ascii", na.value=-9999)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about this package but you should be able to do what you want with a loop:

```
setwd("C:/Users/xblajo/Desktop/New folder/2")
file_names <- list.files(pattern = '*.asc')

for (i in 1:length(file_names)){

    asc <- raster(file_names[i])

    NAvalue(asc) <- -1

    writeRaster(asc,
                filename = file_names[i], 
                format="ascii",
                na.value=-9999)
}
```

Comment: Great, this is what I wanted. But in order to not overwrite the old files I added a file.path in the writeRaster function: `writeRaster(asc,
              filename = file.path("C:/Users/xblajo/Desktop/New folder/3", file_names[i]),
              format="ascii",
              na.value=-9999)`

Comment: Ah, I see. Pleased I can help!